# How to protect a virtualhost by Both IP OR password

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, http-basic-authentication

I have managed to password protect a `virtualhost` by using this:

```
     <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from office-ip-1 office-ip-2
    </Proxy>
```

It works fine as far as it's accessed from our office (the IP used are office static IPs) . Now I want to give access to the web application for some people who might be working from home thus using different IPs (not static IP). So what I want to achieve is that if I am in the office , I can have access without password challenge but when am not in the office a basic auth challenge prompt should pop up.

Is it possible to have this hybrid setup in `apache2` under `ubuntu 12.04` ? If yes kindly show the way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache's [Satisfy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#satisfy) directive for that:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName intranet
AuthUserFile /www/passwd/users
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from internal.com
Satisfy any
```

More info in the [Apache wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/BypassAuthenticationOrAuthorizationRequirements).